# Can't pip install anything EnvironmentError: [Errno 2]

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, prompt-toolkit

Windows 10

I'm trying to pip install stuff, however since today I can't install anything because I keep getting the following error:

Cold not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\behherder\anaconda3\envs\dlc\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit-2.0.7.dist-info\METADATA'

However, if I go there, the file exists. So might that it gets deleted before, and the placed back after the error?

It happens with everything I'm trying to install or upgrade.

I tried upgrading PIP, got that error. Any other install, that error....

Anyone knows what's wrong and how to solve?
Or need any more info?

Thanks!

Comment: A solution that worked for me: go into  `c:\users\behherder\anaconda3\envs\dlc\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit-2.0.7.dist-info` and type in a command line : `cp metadata.json METADATA`